# PHP include not working on new LAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, lamp

I am working on converting an application I wrote in .NET over to a LAMP server.

I built a very basic PHP file that connects to a MySQL database and creates a drop-down list of usernames.  This works fine by itself, and by executing it from the command line using "PHP -f file.php":

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database");

$sql = "SELECT Username,Guid FROM Usernames";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<td><select name='users'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<option value='" . $row['Guid'] . "'>" . $row['Username'] . "  </option>";
}   

echo "</select></td></tr> ";
?>
```

HOWEVER, when I try to include this file in an html file, it simply does not display, and I am not getting any errors.  Here is the source from the basic HTML file:

```
<HTML>
<H1>This is my homepage</H1>
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include 'ShowData.php';?>
</HTML>
```

My question is this: does apache2 natively allow for php include?  In my case, both files are in the same directory "/var/www/html/".  Or am I missing some base configuration somewhere to allow this?  My LAMP server is a brand new install of Ubuntu 14LTS. LAMP was installed using the published "apt-get" commands.

Comment: so you open the page in browser? right-click -page source? what is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run php in a .html file change the extension to .php

Comment: Doh!  That was it!  Thank you!  How do I mark that as the answer?

Comment: should be able to near the arrows i believe